# Единожды вызываемая функция

Tags: c++

Как при создании объекта класса вызвать функцию, которую в дальнейшем нельзя будет вызывать (ни с помощью данного экземпляра, ни других экземпляров этого класса)?

Comment: сделайте статическую переменную и меняйте при первом вызове ей значение

Comment: @splash58 хранить ради этого целую переменную???!!!

Comment: @hero это простейший вариант.

Comment: @hero я думаю, любой другой код займет больше, чем байт на класс

Comment: Формально вызвать-то можно будет, другое дело, что она ничего не будет делать. Но вопрос-то сформулирован не так...

Comment: _Целую_ переменную? Вы наверное имели ввиду _всего одну_ переменную? Вам жалко одного байта?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Для этого в C++ есть специальная функция и флаг, делается это так:

```
std::once_flag flag;
//...
class Class
{
    Class()
    {
        std::call_once(flag, [this]{ SomeMethod(); });
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {...}
}
```

Таким образом мы вызовем `SomeMethod()` в конструкторе однажды, но это не запретит вызывать этот метод в других местах программы, поэтому его можно сделать приватным, но это не запретит вызов приватного метода в других методах класса. Для того, чтобы полностью исключить повторный вызов какого-либо кода, нужно весь этот код поместить в лямбду, которая передаётся в `std::call_once`

```
std::once_flag flag;
//...
class Class
{
    Class()
    {
        std::call_once(flag, [this]
        { 
            // Тут будет код, который нужно вызывать лишь единожды
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете показать, как это в моём случае будет выглядеть?

Comment: @hero, для начала покажите Ваш случай. У Вас в вопросе слишком мало данных

Comment: Просто непонятно для чего `[]`, функция должна вызываться в функторе что ли?

Comment: @hero, это лямбда. Необязательно её использовать, конечно, просто так проще. Всё зависит от того, какую функцию Вы вызываете

Comment: Я вызываю функцию из области видимости класса при его создании один раз

Comment: @hero, метод класса, или свободная функция?

Comment: Метод класса...

Comment: @hero, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!

Comment: Формально никто не мешает вызвать `SomeMethod` отдельно - http://ideone.com/hPeUbN Вопрос же стоит *"которую в дальнейшем нельзя будет вызывать (ни с помощью данного экземпляра, ни других экземпляров этого класса)"*. В лучшем случае это должна быть лямбда, область видимости которой - конструктор, но никак не функция из области видимости класса. По-моему, вопрос стоит переформулировать более корректно :)

Comment: @Harry, ну тогда просто перенести вызов `call_once` в функцию, думаю, что автор разберётся.

Comment: @hero, прочитайте 2 комментария выше

Comment: @ixSci Понимаете, лично я воспринял вопрос так, что запрет повторного вызова - на уровне компилятора, а это невозможно ну никак. Imho. Наверное, я чересчур формалист, да, но ведь и "чтоб больше нельзя было вызвать" - это полный запрет на вызов. А не "чтобы вызов вернулся, ничего не делая", например...

Comment: @Harry, а зачем такое может быть? Чем ситуации будут отличаться? Человек формулирует вопрос в рамках своего понимания темы, озвучивает желание — оно не всегда чёткое, поэтому ожидать чётких и формальных вопросов не стоит, я считаю.

Comment: @Harry `someMethod()` у меня в `private` секции

Comment: @ixSci Ну, я сам иногда задаю очень теоретичные вопросы... :) И меня этот вопрос заинтересовал именно с этой точки зрения. По здравом размышлении пришел к выводу, что для *функции-члена* это нереально. Но хотел бы убедиться, чтоб гуру то же самое сказали :)

Comment: @ixSci, Это всё хорошо, но! разве если экземпляр класса был создан до того, как установлен флаг, вызов не произойдёт?

Comment: @Isaev, не совсем понял, что Вы имеет в виду, но тот код, что находится в лямбде, которая передаётся в `call_once`, гарантировано будет вызван лишь один раз.

Answer (score 7):

Просто заведите статическую переменную-флаг и обрабатывайте его:

```
foo::foo()
{
    static bool once = true;
    if(once)
    {
        once = false;
        bar();
    }
}
```

Второй вариант более элегантный, но работает только если `bar` возвращает какое-либо значение, то есть не `void`:

```
int bar();

foo::foo()
{
    static const auto once = bar();
}
```

Comment: Интересно, начнутся ли тут сейчас дебаты о *singleton*-ах?

Comment: @avp, а больше не о чем дебатировать, синглтоны теперь в C++ имеют один вид и пишутся элементарно.

Comment: @ixSci, и как же их теперь канонически надо писать?

Comment: @avp, `static Object& instance(){static Object instance; return instance;}`. По вкусу, можно возвращать указатель

Comment: @ixSci, тогда я не что-то не понимаю. Вопрос ТС это фактически про singleton. Почему же среди ответов нет Вашего варианта, а есть 2 других и оба сильно заплюсованы?

Comment: @avp, вопрос можно свести к синглтону, но он не о нём. Так, Cerbo, в целом и привёл пример, сведённый к синглтону, только вместо объекта, он использовал функцию. С чистым синглтоном получилось бы больше кода(добавлять новый класс совершенно не имеет смысла, в рамках данной задачи)

Comment: @ixSci, дело в том, что в многопоточной среде этот код в принципе не безопасен. Поэтому я и упомянул синглтон, но похоже, что тут никто так глубоко не смотрит.

Comment: @avp, мой код полностью потокобезопасен. Про код Cerbo не уверен, но скорее всего тоже должен быть безопасен — нужно штудировать стандарт.

Comment: @ixSci, я про Cerbo. Для безопасности там нужен мьютекс (где и как это написать в крестах -- другой вопрос). Сейчас, если переключение потоков (по прерыванию от таймера) произойдет после if, но до записи false (причем такой, что другие потоки **это увидят**) `bar()` может выполниться не один раз.

Comment: @avp, я говорил про второй кусок. Он, насколько я понимаю, потокобезопасен. Чтобы удостоверится, нужно найти в стандарте, что вызов `bar` является частью инициализации(в чём я почти на 100 уверен). Первый кусок, да, не является безопасным, с точки зрения многопоточной среды.

Comment: @ixSci, второй да. Понятно, что инициализация статиков происходит однократно да вызова main. И вот тут большой вопрос, какое состояние памяти видит bar. (логически продолжая подобные рассуждения приходим к выводу, что С++ не годится для программирования сложных вещей).

Comment: @avp, без обид, но это не C++ не предназначен, а просто Вы его знаете не очень хорошо. Не будет тут статик проинициализирован до main, он будет проинициализирован в момент вызова `foo` и только один раз, гарантировано только одним потоком. Это гарантирует стандарт C++.

Comment: А почему можно свести вопрос к сингтону? Вообще поведение, возможно, необходимое для регистрации каких-то уникальных ID в какой-то фабрике при первом использовании класса. Экземпляров может быть много, а вот выполнять регистрацию можно только раз. @avp, да, тов. ixSCi прав по поводу статиков. Всегда было, что статик уровня функции инициализируюется при первом вызове этой функции, а уровня единицы трансляции - до main. C++11 стал гарантировать что такие инициализации будут потокобезопасными. (почему-то опубликовалось в виде ответа)

Comment: @ixSci, ага (раз гарантируется такое поведение), тогда будет работать. Но С++ все равно не годиться, он слишком сложен, слишком много деталей. Где найти за приемлемую плату грамотных людей на поддержку? Недаром, даже в [opensource](https://www.openhub.net/languages/compare?language_name[]=c&language_name[]=cpp&language_name[]=csharp&language_name[]=java&language_name[]=-1&language_name[]=-1&language_name[]=-1&language_name[]=-1&language_name[]=-1&measure=projects) популярность С и С++ одинакова, а в [Tiobe](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe_index) C популярней вдвое.