# При обращении к статическому полю получаю LNK2001 неразрешённый внешний символ

Tags: c++

Есть класс.

```
class some{
public:
    static int Instances;
    static int TotalSumm;
public:
    some() {  // Конструктор
        Instances = 0;
    }
}
```

Этот код не собирается. Ошибка:

> LNK2001 "неразрешённый внешний символ".

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема у вас в дизайне приложения. Статические поля в классах - редкостная трудноотлаживаемая мерзость.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы **объявили** статическое поле. Но **не определили**.

Добавьте

```
int some::Instances;
int some::TotalSumm;
```

вне класса.

Вдогонку - вам точно надо обнулять *член класса* при создании каждого *экземпляра*?

**Update**. Дабы не нарушать правило одного определения, эти определения должны располагаться в `.cpp`-файле, в единственном экземпляре. При их размещении в заголовочном файле они будут определены в каждом `.cpp`- файле проекта...

Comment: Нет, не надо обнулять член класса. Это просто пример, реальная задача немножко другая. Не хотелось, что бы код можно было найти через поисковики. Но ваш ответ, мне всё равно очень помог.  
А можно как нибудь проинициализировать поле из класса? Например механизмы схожие со статическим конструктором из C#?

Comment: Если вам нужна инициализация - просто инициализируете при определении. Типа `int some::Instances{5};` или `int some::Instances = func();` или, если это что-то серьезнее и имеет свой конструктор - как при определении объекта соответствующего класса. Например, пусть есть класс `test` с конструктором от двух `int`, и в классе `static test T;` - тогда определяете как `test some::T{12,18};` или типа того...

Comment: Добавьте, что это нужно делать в cpp файле, иначе очень быстро придёт odr-violation.

Comment: @ixSci Это будет вторым вопросом :) Может, у человека все в одном файле? :)

Comment: Сейчас в одном, завтра в двух. Не кажется Вам, что это всё-таки стоит упомянуть? Ведь это поможет человеку в дальнейшем. На мой взгляд, это должно быть частью ответа, на такой тривиальный вопрос.

Comment: @ixSci OK, добавил

Comment: @ixSci, а `#pragma once` не поможет при объявлении в h-файле?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет, не тот случай. В каждый `.cpp`-файл все равно войдет - пусть и по одному разу :)

Comment: @Harry, да.. Что-то я не подумал, что cpp тоже много :)

Answer (score 0):

потому что нужно проинициализировать за пределами класса

```
class some{
public:
    static int Instances;
    static int TotalSumm;
public:
    some()
    {  
        Instances = 0;
    }
};

int some::Instances = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    some::Instances = 5;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Инициализировать не обязательно, это не константное поле. А вот определить - да, обязательно...

Comment: А можно как нибудь проинициализировать поле из класса? Например механизмы схожие со статическим конструктором из C#?

Comment: @user211023, аналога статического конструктора в C++ нет, но подобного поведения можно добиться. Посмотрите вот [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516403/Единожды-вызываемая-функция/516414#516414) ответ